# How to execute alert of the audio duration when data is available?

Tags: javascript, function, audio, readystate, onreadystatechange

None of those tricks works for me...

```
var audio=new Audio("sample.mp3");

audio.addEventListener('onreadystatechange',function({alert(audio.duration);});
if(audio.readyState===4){alert(audio.duration);}
audio.onreadystatechange=function(){alert(audio.duration);};
```

I want to execute alert of the audio duration when this data is available (when audio.readyState===4). Well... unless there is another magic to fetch this data as fast as possible (without using settimeout or setInterval)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `oncanplay` event? Something like:

```
var audio=new Audio("sample.mp3");

audio.oncanplay = function(){ alert(audio.duration); };
```

The `oncanplay` event fires when enough information has been and the audio is ready to start playing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() { 
   alert(audio.duration);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding event handler twice and the if needs to be inside

```
var audio=new Audio("sample.mp3");
audio.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if(audio.readyState===4){     
    alert(audio.duration);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var audio=new Audio("sample.mp3");

audio.addEventListener('onreadystatechange',alertAudio;);

function alertAudio(){
if(audio.readyState===4){
 alert(audio.duration);}
 }
```